# How to redirect on a specific page after login with a specific username

Tags: redirect, authentication

I created a login form and I would like if (for example) account contains "doru" name, doru to be redirected to "/admin" link. How can I do that? I tried in this way:

```
$_SESSION['login'] = 'Yes';
        if("username='".htmlentities($_POST['user'])."'"=='doru')
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL=/admin">';
    if("username='".htmlentities($_POST['user'])."'"<>'doru')
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL=profile.php">';
```

Complete code is this: (in romanian, I modified above a few words for you)

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

if(!isset($_GET['actiune'])) $_GET['actiune'] = '';

switch($_GET['actiune'])
{
case 'validare':

$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
if(($_POST['user'] == '') || ($_POST['parola'] == ''))
{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2;URL=index.php\">
            <div align=\"center\"><br /><br /><br /><br />
                <font size=\"6\" color=\"#666666\" face=\"Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif\"><strong>Nu ai completat toate spatiile. Se revine la index...</strong></font><br /><br />

            </div>";
}
else
{
$cerereSQL = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE utilizator='".htmlentities($_POST['user'])."' AND parola='".addentities($_POST['parola'])."'";
$rezultat = mysql_query($cerereSQL);
if(mysql_num_rows($rezultat) == 1)
{
  while($rand = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat))
  {
    $_SESSION['logat'] = 'Da';
            if("utilizator='".htmlentities($_POST['user'])."'"=='doru')
                echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL=/admin">';
        if("utilizator='".htmlentities($_POST['user'])."'"<>'doru')
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL=profil.php">';
  }
}
else
{
print("Nume de utilizator sau parola gresite!");
}

}
break;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bine ai venit!</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="index.php?actiune=validare">
<table>
<tr>
<td width="10%" align="center" valign="top"><b><font color="black">Nume:</font> </b></td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><input class="input" type="text" name="user" type="text" placeholder="Numele de utilizator." value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="10%" align="center" valign="top"><b><font color="black">Parola:</font> </b></td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><input class="input" type="password" name="parola" type="text" placeholder="Parola ta." value="" /></td>
</tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Trimite" value="Trimite"></td>
<td><input type="reset" name="Reseteaza" value="Reseteaza"></td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I think the problem is in your comparison code.

```
$_SESSION['logat'] = 'Da';
if($_POST['user']=='doru')
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL=/admin">';
if($_POST['user']<>'doru')  // Note: this 'if' is not necessary since it will always be true
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL=profil.php">';
```

How I would do it is:

```
$_SESSION['logat'] = 'Da';
if( $_POST['user'] == 'doru' )
    header( 'Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/admin" );
else if( $_POST['user'] == 'somebody_else' )
    header( 'Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/somewhere_else" );
header( 'Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/profil.php" );
```

You have a `while($rand = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat))` in your code but you never use the `$rand` results.  You could get rid of this altogether or you could use it for the destination location.

First, however, you already know there will only be one row (you have tested that) so you could get rid of the `while()` and just have `$rand = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat)` (I usually use mysql_fetch_assoc() to get at the fields by name). Then just redirect to a location stored in the database.

```
$rand = mysql_fetch_assoc($rezultat);
$_SESSION['logat'] = 'Da';
if( !empty( $rand['startDir'] ) )
    header( 'Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $rand['startDir'] );
header( 'Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/profil.php" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function(a good practice) and use the session as you are using ,

```
// Function
function redirect($url, $statusCode = 0)
{
   header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
   die();
}
```

You can actually save username and login(as boolean)  in session too (find a secure way to save the session)

then use as,

```
if($_SESSION['login'] == TRUE){
  if($_SESSION['username'] == "aaaa"){
   redirect('http://www.xxxx.com/', false);
  }else{
   redirect('http://www.yyyy.com/', false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
if(!headers_sent()) {
//If headers not sent yet... then do php redirect
    header('Location: '.$redirect_url);
    exit;
} else {
//If headers are sent... do javascript redirect... if javascript disabled, do html redirect.
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'window.location.href="'.$redirect_url.'";';
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<noscript>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$redirect_url.'" />';
    echo '</noscript>';
    exit;
}
```